Issue with Build in Wordpress React Theme Developement
I am using create-react-wptheme package to build react theme when I am write npm build command this will build in seperate folder like theme/portfolio/portfolio/
I am using this package https://github.com/devloco/create-react-wptheme
How to solve this.
I need to build react project inside theme/portfolio/

Please check this screen shot https://prnt.sc/bfYPeV2B9D0I
